# Android: Click new image, compress it and upload it to server

Tags: java, android, image-processing, picasso, android-camera-intent

Which is the best way to go about the task?
Either of these question answered would do it-

1) How to compress an image without losing clarity?

or

2) How to start camera on low resolution in our app?

I know how to click images by CameraIntent, or select images through gallery in an application, and also upload it to server. 
But since the images can be too large if clicked by a camera of high pixel density (my 13MP phone's camera click 3MB images) but we cannot upload that. I need the size to be less than 300KB, preferably around 150KB to 200KB without losing the clarity of the pic. Do we have libraries for this in Android?
The pictures would be of hand-written text. 
As of this being impossible, I have tried turning down the resolution of a camera manually to 2MP or VGA, even then the pictures would be clear enough.

Alternatively, if we start Camera on low resolution, that would also do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following function to scale any image to any dimension

```
public static BufferedImage getScaledImage(Image srcImg, int w, int h) {
        BufferedImage resizedImg = new BufferedImage(w, h, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
        Graphics2D g2 = resizedImg.createGraphics();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g2.drawImage(srcImg, 0, 0, w, h, null);
        g2.dispose();
        return resizedImg;
    }
```

To call the function, use the following code:

```
File file = new File(path);
image = ImageIO.read(file);
newImage = getScaledImage(image, int width, int height);
File outputfile = new File("background.png");
ImageIO.write(newImage, "png", outputfile);
```

Answer (score 3):

**First take Your path and call function**

```
String   mImageNewPath=compressImage(imageOldPath);
```

mImageNewPath is the path of Comress image or New Image Of compressed image without loosing quality

**function To Reduce size without Loosing quality**

```
public String compressImage(String imageUri) {

    String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

//      by setting this field as true, the actual bitmap pixels are not loaded in the memory. Just the bounds are loaded. If
//      you try the use the bitmap here, you will get null.
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

    int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
    int actualWidth = options.outWidth;

//      max Height and width values of the compressed image is taken as 816x612

    float maxHeight = 816.0f;
    float maxWidth = 612.0f;
    float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
    float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

//      width and height values are set maintaining the aspect ratio of the image

    if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
        if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {               imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);               actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;             } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
        imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
        actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
        actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
        } else {
        actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
        actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

        }
    }

//      setting inSampleSize value allows to load a scaled down version of the original image

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);

//      inJustDecodeBounds set to false to load the actual bitmap
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

//      this options allow android to claim the bitmap memory if it runs low on memory
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    options.inInputShareable = true;
    options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

    try {
//          load the bitmap from its path
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();

    }
    try {
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
    float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
    float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
    float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
    canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

//      check the rotation of the image and display it properly
    ExifInterface exif;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
            ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
        Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (orientation == 6) {
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        } else if (orientation == 3) {
        matrix.postRotate(180);
        Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        } else if (orientation == 8) {
        matrix.postRotate(270);
        Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        }
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
            scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
            true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FileOutputStream out = null;
    String filename = getFilename();
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(filename);

//          write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by filename.
        scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return filename;
}

public String getFilename() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "Visitor Management/VisitorPicture");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }
    String uriSting = (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "IMG_"+System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
    return uriSting;

    }
    private String getRealPathFromURI(String contentURI) {
    Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(contentURI);
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return contentUri.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(index);
    }
}

public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
    final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height/ (float) reqHeight);
    final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
    inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;      }       final float totalPixels = width * height;       final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;       while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
    inSampleSize++;
}

return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: Is the new image already saved as in this code or do I need to save it?

Comment: by this code new image is saved....See getFilename() there is path.... of new image.....

Comment: When you get this path than if  you want to  remove old image than use new File(path).delete();